# Laravel: Pass the href link from one view into another. Specifically into modal social share buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.4

I got stuck on social media(s) share buttons. I would like to pass the link, from one view (a href tag) into another view that there is a modal div with social network buttons. To be more specific I have a page called /posts with many posts being displayed there and loading by js on every scroll. So those posts have their unique id on the  tag. So I want  to get the following accomplished: Pass the href from that view into another view that is called when the user clicks on the button that also returns the modal with social network buttons. At last there should be the href, passed, into those buttons. **In this case every time the user clicks on share button, the modal opens. Those buttons should post on social networks the specific posts href link.**

> Below there is an image about the share button on header's of each post
>   displayed in the page.

[image]

```
<a data-href="/posts/{{$post->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

> After that modal pop ups, called by the onClick function, in js displaying the social buttons.

[image]

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12 btn-list">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-share facebook" role="button"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Facebook</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 btn-list">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-share google" role="button"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Google+</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 btn-list">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-share pinterest" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Pinterest</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 last">
            <div class="col-md-12 btn-list">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-share viber" role="button"><img style="margin-top: -3px;" src="../fonts/viber1400.png"></i>
Viber</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 btn-list">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-share tumblr" role="button"><i class="fa fa-tumblr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Tumblr</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 btn-list">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-share twitter" role="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Twitter</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to call a bootstrap model from remote url. For Example:

/posts-page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
    <li><a href="/posts/modal/{{$post->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit/Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade text-center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Remote laravel view for the modal content:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <!-- get the post details by using the post id that is passed in url -->
  <p>Social media to this post</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

To generate the social links you can use the [social link generator](http://sharelinkgenerator.com/) and its really helpful.